# OpenGL 3.3 С++ Помогите оптимизировать Класc Plane

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, шейдеры

Написал класс который позволяет рисовать плоскость быстро и без тонны кода. Но несколько десятков плоскостей и все с периодом в несколько секунд на секунду подвисает. Что я не так делаю.

Прошу подметить что класс используется только для вывода квадратов у каждого своя текстура не для моделей.

**Немного добавлю к вопросу,
Как правильно рисовать меши которые каждый кадр уникальные как в это было в OpenGL 2.0 Только в стандарте. OpenGL 3.0**

```
class Plane3_3
{
public:
    //Шейдер программа
    GLuint shaderProgramPlane;

    //Структура одного полигона
    struct Mesh
    {
        GLuint Texture;
        GLuint VAOparam,VBOpoints;
        int Size;
        float R,G,B,A;
    };

    //Временный масив для компиляции в VAO
    vector<GLfloat>Vertex2D;

    //Набор меша 
    std::vector<Mesh>ArrMesh;
    //Екземпляр набора для сброса в масив
    Mesh Temp;


    //Задать цвет
    void Color4f(float R,float G,float B,float A)
    {
        Temp.R = R;
        Temp.G = G;
        Temp.B = B;
        Temp.A = A;
    }

    //Задать цвет в диапазоне  - 255
    void Color4uf(float R,float G,float B,float A)
    {
        Temp.R = R/255;
        Temp.G = G/255;
        Temp.B = B/255;
        Temp.A = A/255;
    }

    //Очистить временные переменные задать текстуру изза нее и цвета не могу месш вклеить в один vao
    void Begin(GLuint Texture)
    {
        Vertex2D.clear();
        Temp.VAOparam = 0;
        Temp.VBOpoints = 0;
        Temp.Texture = Texture;
    }


    //Отрендорить (Скомпилировать) и сбросить в масив
    void End()
    {
    //Создать VAO буфер
    glGenVertexArrays(1,&Temp.VAOparam);
    //Создать VBO буфер
    glGenBuffers(1,&Temp.VBOpoints);

    //Активировать VAO Буфер
    glBindVertexArray(Temp.VBOpoints);
        //Активировать VBO Буфер и связать переменную с буфером
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,Temp.VBOpoints);
            //Скопировать (координаты) в VBO  ==  GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(float)*Vertex2D.size(),&Vertex2D[0],GL_STREAM_DRAW); //GL_STATIC_DRAW GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW GL_STREAM_DRAW
            //Как шейдер должен распознать точку Текстурные координаты
            glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,4*sizeof(GL_FLOAT),(GLvoid*)0);
            //Активировать индекс layout
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


            //Как шейдер должен распознать точку координаты
            glVertexAttribPointer(1,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,4*sizeof(GL_FLOAT),(GLvoid*)(2 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)));
            //Активировать индекс layout
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


        //деактивирую наверное VBO Буфер
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    //деактивирую наверное VAO буфер
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    Temp.Size = Vertex2D.size()/4;

    //Сброс в масив
    ArrMesh.push_back(Temp);
    }

    //Создать шейдер
    void CreateShader()
    {//--------------------------------
    GLuint vertexShader;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    const GLchar* vertexShaderSourse = "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout(location=0) in vec2 TextCord;\n"
        "layout(location=1) in vec2 position;\n"
        "out vec2 TexCoords;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "TexCoords = TextCord;\n"
        "gl_Position = vec4(position.x,position.y,0,1);\n"
        "}\0";
    glShaderSource(vertexShader,1,&vertexShaderSourse,NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    {
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&success);
        if(!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader,512,NULL,infoLog);
            std::cout<<"error vertex shader"<<std::endl<<infoLog<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    













    GLuint fragmentShader;
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    const GLchar* fragmentShaderSourse = "#version 330 core\n"
        "out vec4 color;\n"
        "in vec2 TexCoords;\n"
        "uniform sampler2D ourTexture;\n"
        "uniform vec4 colorUS;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "color = texture(ourTexture, TexCoords)*colorUS;\n"
        "}\n"
        "\0";
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader,1,&fragmentShaderSourse,NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    {
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&success);
        if(!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader,512,NULL,infoLog);
            std::cout<<"Fragment Error"<<std::endl<<infoLog<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    


    shaderProgramPlane = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgramPlane,vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgramPlane,fragmentShader);

    glLinkProgram(shaderProgramPlane);

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    {
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgramPlane,GL_LINK_STATUS,&success);
        if(!success)
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgramPlane,512,NULL,infoLog);
            std::cout<<"error shader"<<std::endl<<infoLog<<std::endl;
        }

    }
    }//--------------------------------













    


    //Добавить точку
    void AddPoint(float tx, float ty,float x,float y)
    {
        Vertex2D.push_back(tx);
        Vertex2D.push_back(ty);

        Vertex2D.push_back(x);
        Vertex2D.push_back(y);
    }



    //Рисовать все
    void Draw()
    {
                
        //Активировать шейдер
        glUseProgram(shaderProgramPlane);

        for(int i = 0; i<ArrMesh.size();i++)
        {

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ArrMesh[i].Texture);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramPlane, "ourTexture"), 0);


        glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramPlane, "colorUS"), ArrMesh[i].R,ArrMesh[i].G,ArrMesh[i].B,ArrMesh[i].A);

        //Активировать vao
        glBindVertexArray(ArrMesh[i].VAOparam);
        //Рисовать масив
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,ArrMesh[i].Size);
        //Не понятно вроде деактивирую
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        }

    }


//Очистить все
    void Clear()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<ArrMesh.size();i++)
        {
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1,&ArrMesh[i].VAOparam);
        glDeleteBuffers(1,&ArrMesh[i].VBOpoints);
        }
        ArrMesh.clear();
    }




    Plane3_3()
    {
        Temp.R = 1;
        Temp.G = 1;
        Temp.B = 1;
        Temp.A = 1;
    }

    ~Plane3_3()
    {
    }
};
```

///
Решил пойти другим путем. Точки статичны, квадрат собирается только раз а модифицируется в нужный с помощью шейдера.

```
/*
Керування через шейдер замість меша напряму (рендор мешів лагає)
Предається стандартний меш координати 1 1 
Текстурні координати 1 1
В такому випадку в шейдер ми передаємо координати меша і текстурного квадрата 
Передеємо розміри обох кубів.
*/

class Square
{
    public:
    //Шейдер программа
    GLuint shaderProgramPlane;






    //Создать шейдер
    void CreateShader()
    {//--------------------------------
    GLuint vertexShader;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    const GLchar* vertexShaderSourse = "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout(location=0) in vec2 TextCord;\n"
        "layout(location=1) in vec2 position;\n"
        "uniform vec2 S;\n"
        "uniform vec2 P;\n"
        "out vec2 TexCoords;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "TexCoords = TextCord;\n"
        "gl_Position = vec4(position.x*S.x+P.x,position.y*S.y+P.y,0,1);\n"
        "}\0";
    glShaderSource(vertexShader,1,&vertexShaderSourse,NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    {
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&success);
        if(!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader,512,NULL,infoLog);
            std::cout<<"error vertex shader"<<std::endl<<infoLog<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    













    GLuint fragmentShader;
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    const GLchar* fragmentShaderSourse = "#version 330 core\n"
        "out vec4 color;\n"
        "in vec2 TexCoords;\n"
        "uniform sampler2D ourTexture;\n"
        "uniform vec4 colorUS;\n"
        "uniform int textureEnable;\n"
        "uniform vec2 Stx;\n" //Розміркуба текстурних кординат
        "uniform vec2 Ptx;\n" //Зміщення текстурних координат, через шейдер
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "vec2 TC = TexCoords;\n"
        "TC.x = TC.x * Stx.x + Ptx.x;\n"
        "TC.y = TC.y * Stx.y + Ptx.y;\n"
    //  "TexCoords.y = (TexCoords.y*Stx.y)+Ptx.y;\n"

        "if(textureEnable)\n"
        "color = texture(ourTexture, TC)*colorUS;\n"
        "else\n"
        "color = colorUS;\n"
        "}\n"
        "\0";
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader,1,&fragmentShaderSourse,NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    {
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&success);
        if(!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader,512,NULL,infoLog);
            std::cout<<"Fragment Error"<<std::endl<<infoLog<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    


    shaderProgramPlane = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgramPlane,vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgramPlane,fragmentShader);

    glLinkProgram(shaderProgramPlane);

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    {
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgramPlane,GL_LINK_STATUS,&success);
        if(!success)
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgramPlane,512,NULL,infoLog);
            std::cout<<"error shader"<<std::endl<<infoLog<<std::endl;
        }

    }
    }//--------------------------------






    GLuint VAOparam,VBOpoints;

    void Comp()
    {
    //Создать VAO буфер
    glGenVertexArrays(1,&VAOparam);
    //Создать VBO буфер
    glGenBuffers(1,&VBOpoints);

    std::vector<float> Vertex2D;


    //Point A
    //tx
    Vertex2D.push_back(0);
    //ty
    Vertex2D.push_back(0);


    //x
    Vertex2D.push_back(-0.5);
    //y
    Vertex2D.push_back(-0.5);





    //Point B

    //tx
    Vertex2D.push_back(1);
    //ty
    Vertex2D.push_back(0);

    //x
    Vertex2D.push_back(0.5);
    //y
    Vertex2D.push_back(-0.5);




    //Point C
    //tx
    Vertex2D.push_back(1);
    //ty
    Vertex2D.push_back(1);


    //x
    Vertex2D.push_back(0.5);
    //y
    Vertex2D.push_back(0.5);


    //Point C
    //tx
    Vertex2D.push_back(1);
    //ty
    Vertex2D.push_back(1);


    //x
    Vertex2D.push_back(0.5);
    //y
    Vertex2D.push_back(0.5);




        //Point A
    //tx
    Vertex2D.push_back(0);
    //ty
    Vertex2D.push_back(0);


    //x
    Vertex2D.push_back(-0.5);
    //y
    Vertex2D.push_back(-0.5);








    //Point D

    //tx
    Vertex2D.push_back(0);
    //ty
    Vertex2D.push_back(1);

    //x
    Vertex2D.push_back(-0.5);
    //y
    Vertex2D.push_back(0.5);


    //Активировать VAO Буфер
    glBindVertexArray(VBOpoints);
        //Активировать VBO Буфер и связать переменную с буфером
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBOpoints);
            //Скопировать (координаты) в VBO  ==  GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(float)*Vertex2D.size(),&Vertex2D[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW); //GL_STATIC_DRAW GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW GL_STREAM_DRAW
            //Как шейдер должен распознать точку Текстурные координаты
            glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,4*sizeof(GL_FLOAT),(GLvoid*)0);
            //Активировать индекс layout
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


            //Как шейдер должен распознать точку координаты
            glVertexAttribPointer(1,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,4*sizeof(GL_FLOAT),(GLvoid*)(2 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)));
            //Активировать индекс layout
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


        //деактивирую наверное VBO Буфер
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    //деактивирую наверное VAO буфер
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
    
    //Розмір і позиція куба
    float SX,SY,X,Y;


    void SetSizeAndPos(float sx,float sy,float x,float y)
    {
        SX = sx;
        SY = sy;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    bool TextureEnable;
    void SetTextureEnable(bool Enable)
    {
        TextureEnable = Enable;
    }

    //Розмір і позиця текстури
    float txSX,txSY,txX,txY;
    void SetTxSizeAndPos(float sx,float sy,float x,float y)
    {
        txSX = sx;
        txSY = sy;
        txX = x;
        txY = y;
    }


    void Draw(GLuint Texture,float R,float G,float B,float A)
    {
                
        //Активировать шейдер
        glUseProgram(shaderProgramPlane);

        if(TextureEnable)
        {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
            glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramPlane, "ourTexture"), 0);
        }

        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramPlane, "textureEnable"), TextureEnable);


        glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramPlane, "colorUS"), R/255,G/255,B/255,A/255);


        glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramPlane, "S"), SX,SY);
        glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramPlane, "P"), X,Y);

        glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramPlane, "Stx"), txSX,txSY);
        glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramPlane, "Ptx"), txX,txY);
        //glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramPlane, "sx"), SX);
        //glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramPlane, "sy"), SY);

        //Активировать vao
        glBindVertexArray(VAOparam);
        //Рисовать масив
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,6);
        //Не понятно вроде деактивирую
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        
    }


    Square()
    {
    }

    ~Square()
    {
    }
};
```

---

```
//Функція малює квадрат по координатам Ця функція для 2.0 стандарту але користувач може вказати свою
void UserOpenGL3_3_DrawPlane(bool TextureEnable,GLuint TextureID,double x1,double y1,double tx1,double ty1,double x2,double y2,double tx2,double ty2,double x3,double y3,double tx3,double ty3,double x4,double y4,double tx4,double ty4,double R,double G,double B,double A)
{
    Square1.SetSizeAndPos(x2-x1,y4-y1,(x1+x2+x3+x4)/4,(y1+y2+y3+y4)/4);
    Square1.SetTxSizeAndPos(tx2-tx1,ty4-ty1,tx1,ty1);
    Square1.SetTextureEnable(TextureEnable);
    Square1.Draw(TextureID,R,G,B,A);
}
```

Comment: В каком месте он подвисает?

Comment: Не получается проверить так как Cout Зависает с учетом всех команд больше

Comment: при чем тут cout?

Comment: А как мен обнаружить где подвисает, сделать вывод перед кажной команды какая область кода исполняется, и увидеть на какой команде подвисает, но консоль из за нескольких сотен вызовов команд почти морозит программу.

Comment: Кстати подвисает с периодом в несколько сотен кадров а не каждый

Comment: Брать отладчик и профилировщик и смотреть.

Comment: Может подскажете как в консоль отладки visual Studio выводить текст,  не уверен что оно в конкретном месте подвисает, такое впечатление что какая-то память пере пережереться в один момент сбрасывается и потом сова засоряется несколько секунд не подвисая а потом снова сброс.

Comment: я почти уверен что зависание в команде End() Где производиться рендер, вариант это решить дать каждой точке цвет и текстуру и рендерить все плоскости за раз, но в это же время это не выход.

Comment: Когда я делал без текстур и цвета ничего не зависало так как рендорил отдельной командой все перед выводом на екран.

Comment: Не надо ничего выводить в консоль. printf-отладка годится для code monkeys. Воспользуйтесь встроенным профилировщиком CPU https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2019 и плагином для профилирования GPU https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-graphics-features Они сразу покажут место застревания. Еще в коде вызов glBindTexture есть - а есть ли отвязка текстуры и сколько там эта текстура живет - неясно. Еще в коде не видно ни единого вызова glGetError.

Comment: Текстуры не погружаться каждый раз они статичны и храниться в своих переменных. Но блоки могут использовать то один то другой идентификатор текстуры. сейчас посмотрю ссылки. А разве текстуры нужно отвязывать?

Comment: Перед разрушением точно стоит отвязывать.

Comment: Вы про то когда программа зароиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
glBindVertexArray(VAOparam);  
glUseProgram(shaderProgramPlane); 
glUniformXXX
glGetUniformLocation
```

Эти штуки не быстры, и их не стоит делать на каждый квадрат, иначе и на сотне виснуть будет.

Надо 1 раз задать параметры, потом рисовать множество объектов.

А меняющиеся каждый фрейм меши можно рисовать так:

```
struct DDLineData
{
    vec3 pos;
    vec4 color;
};
vector<DDLineData> dd_lines;
```

И каждый фрейм:

```
_shader_color.Use();
_shader_color.projection = proj;
_shader_color.view = view;

unsigned int VBO, VAO;
if (!_to_render.GetRBuf().dd_lines.empty())
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    // bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _to_render.GetRBuf().dd_lines.size() * sizeof(DDLineData), _to_render.GetRBuf().dd_lines.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(DDLineData), (void*)offsetof(DDLineData, pos));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(DDLineData), (void*)offsetof(DDLineData, color));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, _to_render.GetRBuf().dd_lines.size());
    // note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the vertex attribute's bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
}
```

По идее нужен DYNAMIC_DRAW но серавно эта штука у меня только для отладки.

Для шейдера я использую https://gitlab.com/nikitasamoukov/codegenshaders и обращения к _shader_color, это по факту вызовы glUseProgram и glUniformXXX.

vec3 из glm.